# wsimport not working with Java 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, wsimport

I have set the java home and classpath correctly.ie. JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
I am trying to generate classes out of wsdl available via http. 
Executing below from command line ie.
**wsimport -keep http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL**
The below is the exception ie.
parsing WSDL...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createElementNS(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.SAX2DOMEx.startElement(SAX2DOMEx.java:148)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.DOMBuilder.startElement(DOMBuilder.java:82)
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.WhitespaceStripper.startElement(WhitespaceStripper.java:94)
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)

I have added jar in my classpath variables as well but still getting the same exception. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was bug with JDK1.7.21 version. I upgraded the JDK to 1.7.51 pointing the JAVA_HOME to this new JDK, tried the command -> wsimport -keep http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL
Issue resolved.